# Trouble getting html email signature to display properly in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook-2010, email-client, signatures

I have created myself a simple email signature in html, he's the code:

```
<html>

<!-- Company logo goes here -->
<div id="far_left" 
    style="width: 50px; 
           height: 50px;
           float: left;
           margin-right: 10px;">
    <img src="logo.png" />
</div>

<!-- Name and occupation goes here -->
<div id="top" 
    style="height: 25px;">
    <span style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, 'Sans Serif'; font-size: 22; color: #464646;"><strong>Dean Grobler</strong>, Programmer</span>
</div>

<!-- Website link and email adress goes here -->
<div id="bottom" 
    style="font-family: Arial, Verdana, 'Sans Serif';
           font-size: 14px;
           color: #464646;
           padding: 5px;
           height: 25px;">
    <a href="http://www.deangrobler.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #84d5f6">www.deangrobler.com</a> | 
    <a href="mailto:dean@deangrobler.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #84d5f6">dean@deangrobler.com</a> 
</div>
```

In thunderbird, and my browsers it displays correctly:

[image]

But alas in Outlook 2010 it does not:

[image]

If it's using the same rendering engine that IE uses, and I bet you it does, I'm not too surprised this is happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add an absolute path to the image with `http://your.domain.com/image.path/logo.png`

Comment: @javabeangrinder - thanks for the tip. I can sort out the image quick enough, it's more the layout here that's the problem... :\

Comment: You're gonna have to get your `<table>`s out again, I'm afraid. Hope this page helps: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I think your layout problem is related to the fact that the image is not loading, so it's not taking up a fixed space. Do your text lines fall under the image even if it loads?

Comment: @Ioana O - Yes even if the image loads the layout remains the same. Have to remember that the div that contains the image has a fixed width and height of 50px; So if there's an image in or not it will still render the same. :)

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I had not looked closely enough at the posted html....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Email clients do not render html in the same way that browsers do. When creating html emails it is much better to use tables. I know this is going against all modern web design, but they are supported by a lot more email clients. Here is a link to the css properties and which clients they are supported by.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: I have done a lot of work on HTML emails for the company I work for currently and there are a number of useful tips that you can learn. Campaign Monitor has the best articles that I have found on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for this answer. My HTML signature breaks in gmail web client and outlook App client. Useful link to thanks! :)